# Code not printing the characters in the array

Tags: c, arrays, regex, printing, character

I have been trying to solve a simple algorithm that basically validates a given email. So if there is a '.' or '+' in the local name, then it should be fine and if it has '.' or '+' in the domain name (a.k.a. after '@'), it's invalid.

Now, I know my method is not efficient, far from it. But I just want to solve the problem at this point. For some reason when I have the following code, the characters in my newArr are being printed:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char email[30] = "DanGitson@gmail.com";
  char newArr[30];
  int at = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    // get the characters after '@'
    if (at == 1) {
      newArr[i] = email[i];
      printf("%c", newArr[i]);
    }
    // if email[i] is equal to '@'
    if(email[i] == 64){
      at = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

But when I have the following code, they are not:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char email[30] = "DanGitson@gmail.com";
  char newArr[30];
  int at = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    // get the characters after '@'
    if (at == 1) {
      newArr[i] = email[i];
    }
    // if email[i] is equal to '@'
    if(email[i] == 64){
      at = 1;
    }
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
    printf("%c", newArr[j]);
  }
}
```

Basically, my approach is to add all of the characters that are after the '@' character. In other words, get the domain and check if there are more than 2 '.'s and if there is a '+' so I can validate whether the email is valid or not.
Also, if you have any suggestions or feedback on my method, I would appreciate it.

Thank you for having read this so far, I am waiting for your responses!

Comment: The most straightforward way to validate an email address is to use the regex pattern from [EmailRegex.com](https://emailregex.com/).

Comment: Why are you using magic numbers? `'@'` is very equivalent to `64` on ASCII-based system.

Comment: You are starting to write `newArr` from a non-zero position. The first characters before it are having indeterminate values.

Comment: Anyway, how about `strcpy( newArr, &email[strcspn(email, "@") + 1])`? https://ideone.com/kEP0Bp

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks so much

Comment: @EugeneSh. `strcpy( newArr, &email[strcspn(email, "@") + 1])` is potential UB when `'@'` is not found as it attempts to access beyond the end of the string.